# Columnvise matrix multiplication with NA values. Difference between m %*% diag(v) and t(t(m) * v)

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

Columnvise multiplication of matrix'es in R when `NA` values are present in the matrix.

The general advice regarding the 'right' way to do columnvise multiplication I R seems to be:

```
m %*% diag(v)
```

in favor of:

```
t(t(m) * v)
```

But when I started using this approach with matrix'es containing `NA` values the resulting matrix had `NA` values for all values in rows containing `NA`

When shifting to calculation by matrix transpose times vector the behavior is as expected.

The `NA` values are expected when doing normal matrix calculus, and I believe that is the sum

```
m[2,2] = 0 * NA + 2 * 4 + 0 * 6 + 0 * 8 + 0 * 10
```

where the `NA` value takes precedence over the 0 value in the multiplication.

Where as the R matrix multiplication `*` does an elementvise multiplication and thereby don't face the 0 * `NA` problem.

Is the a way to change the default rule of `0 * NA == NA` to `== 0`, when doing standard matrix multiplication, so as to gain the benefit of the optimized matrix calculation rutines?

```
m <- as.matrix(seq(1,10))
dim(m) <- c(2,5)               
v <- as.vector(1:5)

m[2,1] <- NA
m2 <- t(t(m) * v)
m3 <- m  %*%  diag(v)

> m2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   15   28   45
[2,]   NA    8   18   32   50
> m3
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   15   28   45
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Thanks

Comment: `%*%` is a primitive and I believe the actual calculation is done by the linked BLAS. Thus, the answer appears to be "no".

Comment: `m * rep(v, each=nrow(m))` is also a way to calculate the same as `t(t(m) * v)`

Comment: `sweep= sweep(m, 2, STATS=v, FUN='*')` also gives the same result - but it seems to be slow comparing to the others.